# Unable to set sslProtocol in app.config on NET Framework 4.8

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding, .net-4.8

I am trying to configure a WCF service through the app.config file so it defaults to getting the TLS settings from the OS (we want the service to use TLS 1.2 as default, actually), and I am trying to follow the [Transport Layer Security (TLS) best practices with the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls) article.

But when I try to add the sslProtocols parameter to the transport attribute, it seems like it does not exist.

Do we lack some Assembly or other dependencies? Did it change from NET Framework 4.8?

Our config file is as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="siiBinding">
                    <security mode="Transport"/>
                </binding>
                <binding name="siiBinding1">
                    <security mode="Transport"/>
                </binding>
                <binding name="siiBinding2">
                    <security mode="Transport"/>
                </binding>
                <binding name="siiBinding3"/>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://www1.agenciatributaria.gob.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="siiBinding" contract="SuministroFactEmitidasReference.siiSOAP" name="SuministroFactEmitidas"/>
            <endpoint address="https://www10.agenciatributaria.gob.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="siiBinding1" contract="SuministroFactEmitidasReference.siiSOAP" name="SuministroFactEmitidasSello"/>
            <endpoint address="https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="siiBinding2" contract="SuministroFactEmitidasReference.siiSOAP" name="SuministroFactEmitidasPruebas"/>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8"/></startup></configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your system.web is similar to the following:

```
<system.web>
       <compilation targetFramework="4.8"></compilation>
       <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" />
</system.web>
```

and transfer mode

```
  <binding name="secureHttpBinding">  
       <security mode="Transport">  
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>  
       </security>  
   </binding>
```

Try adding in global.asax.cs using System.Net.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =  SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

For details you can check the documentation.
[How to: Configure an IIS-hosted WCF service with SSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-an-iis-hosted-wcf-service-with-ssl)
[TcpTransportSecurity.SslProtocols Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.tcptransportsecurity.sslprotocols?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)